# Is trough a part of a sink in a kitchen?

Tags: terminology

I am confused about trough and sink in the context of kitchen. So I googled and got this (img_1).

[image]

Is the red part a trough and blue part a sink?

So, there are 3 troughs and 1 sink in the following image (img_2), right?

[image]

updated, the images above is kept to understand comments history.

consider the following image (img_3).

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific dialect in mind? In my dialect, nothing pictured in your question is a trough.

Comment: Trough is not used in connection with “kitchen sinks” in ordinary Australian usage either. In my usage it most often refers to the low point between two waves (both in the ocean and in the atmosphere as a meteorological word). In less frequent usage it can refer to a large old-fashioned laundry sink or a large drinking place for livestock. I would pronounce it “troff” but a far less common and outdated pronunciation in Australia is “trow” (rhyming with “crow”) - my grandma used this when referring to a century old laundry sink made of wood at her rural property.

Comment: It isn't used that way in British English either. Most of us would probably think of a trough, firstly as the container that pigs eat out of, and then as a low point on the sea's surface or on a graph.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your comments. What is the part pointed out by red arrow in img_2 called in British English?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thanks for your comments. What is the part pointed out by red arrow in img_2 called in ordinary Australian usage?

Comment: I see no arrows. The red circles seem to indicate the two sinks and a unique removable draining tray with fruit in it over one of the sinks. The draining tray has no idiomatic name (since they are not common) just the various descriptions a person might apply to it.  (I suspect Kate Bunting will say the same - our interpretations are virtually identical in substance. @KateBunting - Yes of course, a “pig’s trough” is indeed the most common use of trough in the farmyard sense.)

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Sorry, I meant circles. Your comments makes me clearer. Consider img_3, there are 2 sinks pointed out by red circles. What the whole thing pointed out by blue circle is called?

Comment: We are probably moving beyond the original question now. I think you are getting the idea that “the sink” can actually refer to two sinks combined in one fixture. And before you ask, the sink is installed into a kitchen bench, or more particularly I’d probably call this an island bench.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thank you so much. Sink and island bench are what I had been trying to say. Would you please move your comments to answer? I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trough** is not used in connection with these images. The fixtures with taps over them and drains at their base are all “kitchen ***sinks***”. In images 2 and 3 there are two sinks combined in one fixture and served by one set of taps. These combinations of two sinks may still be referred to singularly as “a **sink**”.

**Trough** is often used to refer to the low point between two waves in the ocean and in the atmosphere (between waves of pressure, as a meteorological word) and even the similar low point between peaks on a graph.

**Trough** is also the container pigs eat out of and, more generally, is the large fixed container (made from wood, metal or, in modern times, plastic) that livestock on a farm eat and drink from.

In less frequent outdated usage **trough** can refer to a large old-fashioned laundry **sink**.

I would pronounce **trough** as “troff” (but a less common, regional and outdated pronunciation in Australia is “trow” - rhyming with “crow”).